# Which Haskell package contains given module

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

I know a Haskell module name, but I can't figure out in what package it is defined. This is bad because I can't compile without a package exposing this module.

Specificaly it is Text.Regex that I can't locate, but I would like to know how to solve that problem in general.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/packages.html

ghc-pkg find-module Text.Regex

But that only works for (a) recent GHCs, and (b) packages installed on your system.

You can also grep through the package file (e.g. /usr/lib/ghc-6.8.2/package.conf) to see what's installed.

You can also use either the haskell API search engines [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or the [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/hackage.html) search engine [hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html).

Text.Regex is in the package regex-base, and a few others built on top of it.

Comment: I could find it only by clicking on a few of the results from hoogle. At the moment there seem to be no easy way to find those packages. Hopefully new release of ghc will fix this issue.

Comment: +1 Hoogle. It is by far the easiest way I have found. Command line stuff is a bit unnecessary when there's a perfectly good search engine option :) (imho)

Comment: That's less helpful when you're offline.  Hopefully such barbarism is rare, but...

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Cabal and you have the package installed, you can just try to compile it with `cabal build`, and Cabal will inform you of which package you forgot to add to your dependencies:

```
Main.hs:1:8:
    Could not find module `Text.Regex':
      It is a member of the hidden package `regex-compat-0.93.1'.
      Perhaps you need to add `regex-compat' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Answer (score 1):

The best tools are:

- [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/); or
- [hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html).

Both are search engines for Haskell modules and functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Debian and the Debian-provided packages, there is a global documentation index at `/usr/share/doc/ghc-doc/html/libraries/index.html` which lists the package in the last column.